# Parse IOS date and set to user's current time zone

Tags: ios, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am new to IOS development. I am receiving a date string from an API and would like to set the time to the user's current time zone. The dateformatter looks like:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'"];
```

I know I can set the timezone like so

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

But is there a way to set it depending on the user's current time zone?

Comment: Date formatters default to the user's timezone. There's no need to set anything. But keep in mind that the string includes a timezone so you should honor that. Do not quote the `Z` in your date format.

Comment: Tried what you suggested but setting the format to @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS" returns nil..

Comment: I didn't say to remove the `Z`, I said to remove the quotes around the `Z`.

Comment: My bad indeed..Time is correctly parse to the current time zone. You would keep a reference to the unparsed Z somewhere else in the model?

Comment: What unparsed `Z`? The `Z` is the timezone. It means UTC. Your date formatter will see the `Z` and parse it properly. There's nothing to reference.

Comment: Right, I misunderstood something in your first answer. Thanks for the help!